# problem converting custom nodetree template to multi file addon, @classmethod

Tags: python

fighting hard on this one, trying to use the custom nodetree template into multi files addon, moving the @classmethod to another file (same folder).

```
...

if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(mycustomtreenode)  
else:
    from . import mycustomtreenode

import bpy
from bpy.types import NodeTree, Node, NodeSocket

# Implementation of custom nodes from Python


# Derived from the NodeTree base type, similar to Menu, Operator, Panel, etc.
class MyCustomTree(NodeTree):
    # Description string
    '''A custom node tree type that will show up in the editor type list'''
    # Optional identifier string. If not explicitly defined, the python class name is used.
    bl_idname = 'CustomTreeType'
    # Label for nice name display
    bl_label = "Custom Node Tree"
    # Icon identifier
    bl_icon = 'NODETREE'


# Custom socket type
class MyCustomSocket(NodeSocket):
    # Description string
    '''Custom node socket type'''
    # Optional identifier string. If not explicitly defined, the python class name is used.
    bl_idname = 'CustomSocketType'
    # Label for nice name display
    bl_label = "Custom Node Socket"

    # Enum items list
    my_items = (
        ('DOWN', "Down", "Where your feet are"),
        ('UP', "Up", "Where your head should be"),
        ('LEFT', "Left", "Not right"),
        ('RIGHT', "Right", "Not left"),
    )

    my_enum_prop: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Direction",
        description="Just an example",
        items=my_items,
        default='UP',
    )

    # Optional function for drawing the socket input value
    def draw(self, context, layout, node, text):
        if self.is_output or self.is_linked:
            layout.label(text=text)
        else:
            layout.prop(self, "my_enum_prop", text=text)

    # Socket color
    def draw_color(self, context, node):
        return (1.0, 0.4, 0.216, 0.5)

# ###################################################
# THIS IS THE CLASS I WANT TO MOVE TO ANOTHER FILE
# ####################################################

# Mix-in class for all custom nodes in this tree type.
# Defines a poll function to enable instantiation.
#class MyCustomTreeNode:
    #@classmethod
    #def poll(cls, ntree):
        #return ntree.bl_idname == 'CustomTreeType'


# Derived from the Node base type.
class MyCustomNode(MyCustomTreeNode, Node):
    # === Basics ===
    # Description string
    '''A custom node'''
    # Optional identifier string. If not explicitly defined, the python class name is used.
    bl_idname = 'CustomNodeType'
    # Label for nice name display
    bl_label = "Custom Node"
    # Icon identifier
    bl_icon = 'SOUND'

    # === Custom Properties ===
    # These work just like custom properties in ID data blocks
    # Extensive information can be found under
    # http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties
    my_string_prop: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    my_float_prop: bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=3.1415926)

    # === Optional Functions ===
    # Initialization function, called when a new node is created.
    # This is the most common place to create the sockets for a node, as shown below.
    # NOTE: this is not the same as the standard __init__ function in Python, which is
    #       a purely internal Python method and unknown to the node system!
    def init(self, context):
        self.inputs.new('CustomSocketType', "Hello")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', "World")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketVector', "!")

        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor', "How")
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor', "are")
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', "you")

    # Copy function to initialize a copied node from an existing one.
    def copy(self, node):
        print("Copying from node ", node)

    # Free function to clean up on removal.
    def free(self):
        print("Removing node ", self, ", Goodbye!")

    # Additional buttons displayed on the node.
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.label(text="Node settings")
        layout.prop(self, "my_float_prop")

    # Detail buttons in the sidebar.
    # If this function is not defined, the draw_buttons function is used instead
    def draw_buttons_ext(self, context, layout):
        layout.prop(self, "my_float_prop")
        # my_string_prop button will only be visible in the sidebar
        layout.prop(self, "my_string_prop")

    # Optional: custom label
    # Explicit user label overrides this, but here we can define a label dynamically
    def draw_label(self):
        return "I am a custom node"


### Node Categories ###
# Node categories are a python system for automatically
# extending the Add menu, toolbar panels and search operator.
# For more examples see release/scripts/startup/nodeitems_builtins.py

import nodeitems_utils
from nodeitems_utils import NodeCategory, NodeItem

# our own base class with an appropriate poll function,
# so the categories only show up in our own tree type


class MyNodeCategory(NodeCategory):
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.space_data.tree_type == 'CustomTreeType'


# all categories in a list
node_categories = [
    # identifier, label, items list
    MyNodeCategory('SOMENODES', "Some Nodes", items=[
        # our basic node
        NodeItem("CustomNodeType"),
    ]),
    MyNodeCategory('OTHERNODES', "Other Nodes", items=[
        # the node item can have additional settings,
        # which are applied to new nodes
        # NOTE: settings values are stored as string expressions,
        # for this reason they should be converted to strings using repr()
        NodeItem("CustomNodeType", label="Node A", settings={
            "my_string_prop": repr("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"),
            "my_float_prop": repr(1.0),
        }),
        NodeItem("CustomNodeType", label="Node B", settings={
            "my_string_prop": repr("consectetur adipisicing elit"),
            "my_float_prop": repr(2.0),
        }),
    ]),
]

classes = (
    MyCustomTree,
    MyCustomSocket,
    MyCustomNode,
)


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    nodeitems_utils.register_node_categories('CUSTOM_NODES', node_categories)


def unregister():
    nodeitems_utils.unregister_node_categories('CUSTOM_NODES')

    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

this is now my customtreenode.py

```
...
import bpy
from bpy.types import NodeTree, Node, NodeSocket

class MyCustomTreeNode:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, ntree):
        return ntree.bl_idname == 'CustomTreeType'
```

it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.3\3.3\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\SILVIA IBAÑEZ\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\testAddon_v1\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import mycustomnodes
  File "C:\Users\SILVIA IBAÑEZ\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\testAddon_v1\mycustomnodes.py", line 5, in <module>
    class MyCustomNode(MyCustomTreeNode, Node):
NameError: name 'MyCustomTreeNode' is not defined
```

I dont have any trouble making a multi-files addon, but with the nodetree, i dont see what i am missing, thanks for your help

EDIT:
i found this in BPY documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.html?highlight=register_class#bpy.utils.register_class

> Note: If the class has a register class method it will be called
> before registration.

but still, when importing this mixin class from another file, i got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I did this myself with this folder structure:

```
add_on
  |
  -> node_tree
        |
        ->nodes
        |   |
        |   -> my_node
        |
        ->sockets
```

Folder Contents:

```
add_on folder:
  __init__.py Initialization of the addon following:
              [Multi File Add-on For Blender][1]

  node_tree subfolder:
     __init__.py Initialization file with NodeTree subclass.
                 Makes node_tree a package.
    categories.py File with the nodeitems_utils.NodeCategory sub class.

    nodes sub folder:
        __init__.py Empty. Makes nodes a subpackage.
        custom_node.py File with the Mix-in class you want to move.

        my_node subfolder:
             __init__.py File (*) See below 

    sockets subfolder:
      __init__.py Empty. Makes sockets a subpackage.
      my_socket.py File with a bpy.types.NodeSocket 
                   subclass defining a socket type.
```

In the my_node **init**.py the imports are done like this:

```
import bpy
from .. import custom_node
from ... import sockets

class MyNode(custom_node.CustomTreeNode, bpy.types.Node):
    """What this node does."""
    bl_idname = 'MyNode'
    bl_label = 'MyNode'
    bl_icon = 'NODE'  # TODO: Uses Blender default NODE Icon. 
                      # A custom icon can be used too.
    
    # Initialization function, called when a new node is created.
    # This is the most common place to create the sockets for a node, as shown below.
    # NOTE: this is not the same as the standard __init__ function in Python, which is a purely internal Python method,
    # and unknown to the node system!
    self.inputs.new('MySocketType', 'My Socket Name')

    # Optional: custom label
    # Explicit user label overrides this.
    # But here we can define a label dynamically
    def draw_label(self):
        return F'My Custom Node Label'
```

I learned this structure through experimentation, but more importantly, by reviewing the code of Animation Nodes, Sverchock, Sorcar and Serpens (Commercial add-on).

Hope this one helps. David